# 'Porting' conio.h written code to curses.h

Tags: c++, linux, windows, curses, conio

I want to port a simple console application to run on Linux terminal with keeping its current behavior as much as possible. It is a little CLI-based game using conio.h at Windows, I would like to port it to Linux.

All the conio.h specific lines are these:

```
...  
  HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;
  GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
  cursorInfo.bVisible = false; // set the cursor visibility
  SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
  short int CX=0, CY=0;
        COORD coord;
        coord.X = CX;
        coord.Y = CY;
...
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
...
```

(and: should I use curses.h or ncurses.h?)

Comment: [Porting an old DOS TUI to ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43076155/995714)

Comment: Those are Windows console calls, not what I'd think of as "conio.h" (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h ).

Comment: Other people have different ideas - see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4234/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

`conio.h` questions usually ask about `getch`, which corresponds roughly to the upper-level (curses) `getch`.  However most of `conio.h` is lower-level, like this, and would be done using terminfo, e.g., `tigetstr`, `tparm`, `tputs`, using `"civis"` (cursor-invisible), and `"cup"` (cursor-position).  Those functions are defined via `<term.h>`.

Likely the program uses other features (and there are no useful tutorials on porting from `conio.h` to curses).  In curses, the mentioned features would be [curs_set](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-curs_set) and [move](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html).

Further reading (terminfo):

- [curses interfaces to terminfo database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html)
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)